# how to prevent swap space from formatting during installation?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, live-usb, 20.04, swap

I'm using Kali Linux 2020.02 and I have been waiting for new LTS version for ubuntu which is released recently.now I have to install Ubuntu 20.04 in the same disk on a different partition. For that, I created a Bootable USB using Rufus.

During Installation, After creating a partition for root, home and swap from the unallocated space now the installer has to format newly created partitions. However, it's showing a prompt to format both the swap spaces even the other distro's(kali) swap which I don't want it to happen.

What if I format both the swaps will that unmount swap space from kali `/etc/fstab`

If **yes** how to prevent other distro's swap space from formatting so that there is no need to add swap space again in kali by editing `fstab`?

If **no** I can begin the installation further.

Being curious even after **no** what can be done to stop it from formatting let's say if hibernated data is important. Can I lock it using GParted?

Note - As I do hibernation more often thus, I cannot use one common swap space for multiple OSes.

[image]

Comment: Nowadays Ubuntu prefers to create it's own swap file, not a swap partition. If there is already swap space the installer will format it but that only deletes the current info on it, not generally a big deal. after installing you can create or copy a swap file and go to /etc/fstab and set Ubuntu to boot the swap file if you don't like it sharing Kali's swap file.

Comment: I got your point but As you said **not generally a big deal**  how can we create swap file during the installation without affecting other distro's swap file?

Comment: I recall using the instructions on It's FOSS when stopping Ubuntu on one drive from using swap partition on another drive and make it use it's own swapfile. https://itsfoss.com/create-swap-file-linux/ I don't know how to do it during installation though.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution for your problem is to not create a swap partition in the installation wizard at all and safely create it after the installation.

You can create your own swapfile via

```
sudo fallocate -l 1G /swapfile  #Replace the parameter to suit your needs
sudo mkswap /swapfile
sudo chown 0600 /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile
```

And you can add that swapfile to the `/etc/fstab` to mount it automatically at boot-time.And also it doesn't require a whole partition for it.

Comment: I understood the OP does not want to format the existing swap partition during Install. No matter what the user does, the installation wizard automatically formats any existing swap partition it sees and adds it to fstab

Comment: @C.S.Cameron There should be an option to not format the partition (if I remember correctly )

Comment: @Mousav From the title of the question and the OP's comments, I believe that option is the whole point of the question. Do you know enable that option?

Answer (score 0):

### Install Ubuntu Without Formatting Existing Kali Linux Swap Partition

I don't think there is a problem installing Ubuntu on a computer with an existing Swap partition but this is the users choice.

If you don't want the installer to format and use the existing swap partition, the only way I know to avoid it is to first make a Full install to an external USB drive same as installing to HDD.

The computer used for this install must not have an existing swap partition installed on it. In your case the Kali drive should be unplugged.

Use the same BIOS/UEFI mode Kali uses for the install.

After the install to USB, plug the Kali drive back in and use GParted to copy/paste the new Ubuntu partition from the USB to empty space on the Kali drive.

Then add the Ubuntu installation to the existing boot loader. ie `sudo update-grub,` if your Kali is using GRUB2 bootloader.

Comment: I believe this is quite a useful way, but having a simple option for not to format in the first place could be a time saver.